# How to wait on celery producer for its tasks completions by celery worker

Tags: python, celery

I have been trying a lot lately to come up with a good approach to wait on a producer of tasks for its completion by celery worker. I came up with one approach but that doesn't seem to work fast enough, Here it is:

celery producer:

```
leafs = []

def chain_tasks():
    for i in range(1, 10):
        p1 = ping1.si(i)
        p2 = ping2.si(i)
        p3 = ping3.si(i)
        p4 = ping4.si(i)
        mychain = chain(p1, p2, p3, p4)
        leaf_id = mychain.apply_async()
        leafs.append(leaf_id)
    print('[INFO] Total leafs ->', leafs)


def _cancel_tasks(msg):
    print("[ERROR] Dummy Task canceller->", msg)

def parent_succeeds(t):
    if t.parent == None:
        return True
    else:
        parent_succeeded = True
        parent = t.parent
        if parent.state == 'PENDING':
            parent_succeeded = parent_succeeds(parent)
        if not parent_succeeded:
            return False
        print('[INFO] Waiting on parentTask({0})...at {1} - {2}'.format(parent, datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"), parent.state), end='')
        parent.wait(propagate=True)
        print('Done.')
        return parent.state != 'FAILURE'

def wait_for_comp():
    print("[INFO] Waiting for celery to finish...")
    max_fail = round(len(leafs) / 2)
    fail_count = 0
    for t in leafs:
        if fail_count <= max_fail:
            print('[INFO] Waiting on Task({0})...at {1}'.format(t, datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")))
            try:
                if parent_succeeds(t):
                    t.wait(propagate=True)
                else:
                    print('[ERROR] One of the parent failed -> ', t.parent)
            except Exception as e:
                fail_count += 1
                print('[ERROR] Exception Occurred [' + datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S") + '] ->', str(e), fail_count)
                print('[ERROR] Traceback [' + datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S") + '] ->', traceback.format_exc())
        else:
            print("[ERROR] Failed!")
            _cancel_tasks('failure of more than half tasks({0}/{1})'.format(fail_count, max_fail))
            break
    print("[INFO] Done.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    time_start = time.time()
    chain_tasks()
    wait_for_comp()
    print('Finish time %s', time.time() - time_start)
```

One things that's wrong with this approach is that it WAITS on a sequence(for-loop) of tasks that doesn't necessarily need to be maintained at worker side as worker execution is based on rabbit-mq entry. So it involves lot of waiting.

Is there an alternative way to make the wait more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

If I am not missing something important, then the simple solution is to change the `leaf_id = mychain.apply_async()` to something like:

```
result_as = mychain.apply_async()
result = result_as.get()  # will block until the task is done
```

Note: [do not call get() in your tasks](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks).

Comment: The problem here is, It will run sequentially then. I want it to run in parallel fashion and it does in the current approach since forloop throw these tasks into the Queue asynchronously

Comment: Ah, right, completely missed that. Sorry. The way to do this is to add your chains to a Chord. That way the chains will execute concurrently, and the final task will collect results.

Comment: But that requires a backend such as redis, etc.(It doesn't work with rpc://) Can't we achieve that without using chords?

Comment: As far as I know (and I am not a Celery expert) - you will need a result backend...

Comment: I even tried Chord. But chord hangs in **result.get()** if one of the intermediate tasks fail under chain. I.e., 
```->header = [chain(ping1.si(i), ping2.si(i), ping3.si(i), ping4.si(i)) for i in range(2, 5)]```
```->result = chord(header)(cl)```
```->result.get()``` #hangs if ping1 or ping2 task fails. It can only track the last one(ping4) and parent(ping3) failure through the use of _propagate_ and _follow_parents_